# Plotting Contours with x, y, z values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, contour

I am trying to create a contour plot of 1000 data points. I have the matrix with all of the values in it. Here is my code.

```
mu1 <- rbind(2, 2)
mu2 <- rbind(-2, -2)
sigma1 <- rbind(c(.6, 0), c(0, .6))
simga2 <- sigma1
det1 <- det(sigma1)
det2 <- det1
inv1 <- solve(sigma1)
inv2 <- inv1
x <- runif(1000, -5, 5)
y <- runif(1000, -5, 5)
w <- rbind(x, y)
ratio <- function(v){
  quotient <- (exp((-1/2)*t(v-mu1)%*%inv1%*%(v-mu1)))/(exp((-1/2)*t(v-mu2)%*%inv2%*%(v-mu2)))
  return(quotient)
}
z <- apply(w, 2, ratio)
round.z <- round(z, digits=0)
df <- cbind(x, y, z, round.z)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

I want to plot the contours of x and y by the round.z values including where round.z=1. I know that the contour where round.z=1 should be the line y=-x, but I don't know how to get it to show up. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contour` and related functions in R want to have the data on a grid, not a random sample like yours.  The `akima::interp` function can convert your data to this format.  For example, after running your code,

```
library(akima)
grid <- with(df, interp(x, y, round.z))
contour(grid, levels = 10^(0:10))
```

which produces this image:
[image]